# is there a max number of ibeacons transmitting simultaneously?

Tags: ibeacon

What is the maximum number of transmitting beacons in the same room? Is it possible that there will be collision? How can be modified the ibeacon firmware to prevent wrong behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We build and test iBeacons at Radius Networks, so we often have many transmitting simultaneously.  I have witnessed iOS and Android devices ranging several dozen at the same time.

There is no hard limit in the operating systems and detection libraries.  You may begin to run into trouble when several hundred are visible simultaneously because your software might slow down when hundreds must be processed every second. (Better make sure your code is fast!) Also, radio interference will begin to become problematic with many hundred transmitting in the same place. See [this discussion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21991/how-many-active-bluetooth-devices-can-i-reliably-detect-in-a-single-space).

An iBeacon itself is a transmit-only device, so it doesn't really care how many other devices are around.  No matter how noisy the room gets, it will just keep transmitting.  There is therefore not anything you need to do to iBeacon firmware "to prevent wrong behaviour".

Comment: Hi David, thank fro you answer, but if the beacon is transmitting only, how will it be possible to change parameters: minor, major, etc..?

Answer (score 0):

Sfavilla, I develop beacons at Gelo and can confirm David's answer. We've seen a few hundred in a single location work fine. We've also seen some older iPod Touches crash more often and intermittently miss beacons.

There will be a lot potential collisions where interference is caused an an advertisement from one beacon will be ignored. I've seen *a lot* sniffing the airwaves finding all of the advertisements that fail CRC checks. The more beacons you have the more errors that will exist.

Bluetooth Low Energy however is designed to be robust and work in these kinds of environments so all is not lost.

The biggest issue I've seen with processing advertisements is the fact that CoreBluetooth more likely crashes before your code becomes an issue. Apple I believe is working to fix that. CoreBluetooth also doesn't crash the same across iOS devices. I am guessing there are varying degrees of memory allocated to CoreBluetooth and its cache because iPhone 5s and above work way better than iPod 4s and older iPod Touches.